# rails: Pre-fill a form with users image imported from oauth-twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, twitter-oauth

So I have a web app that let users sign up with twitter. So there profile pictures & name are associated to their users accounts.

They can also crate profiles (another model), in these profiles they can fill in name, photos and more.

I succeeded to pre-fill the name field from users name on twitter like this:

In my *profiles_controller.rb*:

```
def new
@profile = Profile.new :twitter => current_user.name   
end
```

What I would like to do is to import users images (imported from twitter) inside this form.

So i tried:

```
  def new
    @pin = Pin.new :twitter => current_user.name, :image => current_user.image
  end
```

But all I get in my form is a broken image preview.

As I am using paperclip to upload images on my app, is there a way to transfer a twitter image to paperclip inside a form ? I am not sure how to do it. Any helps would be lovely appreciated.

Edit:

Here is the part of my user model where I retrieve user image from twitter Oauth:
*User.rb*:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.nickname
      user.image = auth["info"]["image"].sub("_normal", "")
    end
  end
```

I call the user image like this in my views:

```
<%= image_tag user.image %>
```

But the questions is how could I upload the User image to the profile form:

I have: *app/profile/views/_form.html.erb*:

```
<%= f.file_field :image %>
```

How could I trick this f.file_field to automatically import users.image if he doesn't want to uplaod a different profile picture form its twitter profile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to do this.  Twitter provides a link to the profile image, if you check the documentation...

```
"profile_image_url": 
         "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png"
```

Store the URL in the user record and Use the url to display the image if you have no user-uploaded image available.

You can refresh it to the latest URL on every oAuth log in, and that way you always show the user's latest Twitter profile image.

EDIT

So, create a field in your User model to store the twitter image url...

```
rails g migration AddTwitterImageToUser twitter_image.string
rake db:migrate
```

Populate the field when you log in via Twitter...

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.nickname
      user.twitter_image = auth.info.profile_image_url
    end
  end
```

Then to display...

```
<% if user && user.twitter_image.present? %>
  <img src="<%= user.twitter_image %>" >
<% end %>
```

I'm not personally aware of "nickname" being an available field in the Twitter API so I'm not positive about the contents of the `info` attribute in the `auth` object... you may want to confirm image url is available by inpecting the object... dump it to the logger or use `pry`.

Comment: Hey Steve, thanks for your answer. It's a good alternative, you're right. I am not sure how I can display the image from the url though? Any ideas to put me on track?

Comment: Can you post the code where you retrieve the user record based on oAuth?

Comment: Sure thing @SteveTurczyn I edited my question with more infos. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I've added more info to my answer, hope it helps.